# regex get last two paths of directory

Tags: php, regex

```
Given
http://host/test/google/oop/a/a
```

I'm trying to retrieve the last two elements seperated by / so I can do 
$myvar = "a_a";. There could be an ending / or not it needs to work both ways.

I have the following working but it's pretty ugly, how else could I do it?

```
$href = preg_split("/[\/]+/", "http://host/test/google/oop/a/a");
$myvar = $href[count($href)-3] . "_" . $href[count($href)-2];
```

Comment: A quick hack would be to explode your URL on the slash, and then look at the last two indexes of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could do it this way:

```
<?php 
$link = 'http://host/test/google/oop/a/a';

$linkParts=explode('/',rtrim($link,'/'));
$count=count($linkParts);

$desired = $linkParts[$count-2].'_'.$linkParts[$count-1];

echo $desired; //a_a
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that your current method is good - it's succinct, makes sense, and not over-complicated.

If you wanted to use regex you could try regex (@ is the delimiter instead of `/`, it makes escaping a little simpler):

```
@/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$@
```

And groups `\1_\2` would be your `$myvar`.

The regex looks for the bit of your string that starts from a `/` and has exactly 1 more `/` in the string (unless there is a `/` at the end of the string with no following text, in which case you can have one extra). (Note the '$' in the regex meaning "end of string").

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit less ugly (and probably faster) way.

```
implode('_', array_slice(explode('/', rtrim($url, '/')), -2, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('%/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?!.*/)%', $subject, $result)
```

I've used a negative look ahead to ensure the match is only selecting the last block